# Bash command echo doesn't run

Tags: bash, echo

I started to learn bash scripting. I was trying to upgrade script from tutorial to accept user input for some variables. Input works but I would like to insert echo before typing the variable. I tried different variations of echo (with -e, -n, without any, ...) but echo never shows when i run the script. What I am doing wrong?

```
#! /bin/bash

# make_page - A script to produce an HTML file

# input page's title
echo -e "Hi, type the title: /c "
read TITLE

###### Constants

AUTHOR=$USER
CREATED_ON=$(date +"%x %r %Z")

##### Main

cat <<- _EOF_
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>
        $TITLE
        </TITLE>
        <meta name="author" content="$AUTHOR">
        <meta name="created" content="$CREATED_ON">
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
    <H1>$TITLE</H1>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
_EOF_
```

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: `sh script.sh` works fine for me.

Comment: The script is working perfectly fine, I'm seeing the echo correctly, the script isn't the issue, where are you running the script from?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I run script in xfce4-terminal.

Comment: @Mat I'm going by this [tutorial](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0010.php) so command is make_page > page.html

Comment: @flowit I tried your way and it doesn't work either

Comment: You're sending all your script's output to `page.html`. It can't show up on your console.

Comment: `read -p 'Input prompt: '` would be easier to work with; but scripts which require interactive input are a priori flawed. I understand this is merely for demonstration; hopefully the text you are following will soon teach you better interface manners.

Comment: Thanks to all for help

Answer (score 0):

When you run :

```
make_page > page.html
```

You tell bash to redirect any output to the file "page.html". That's why you don't see the prompt.

What you should do is change this line :

```
cat <<- _EOF_
```

by :

```
cat <<- _EOF_ > page.html
```

This way only the result of the "cat" is redirected to the file.